# .NET Web Form Passing Parameter as SQL Select/Where

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a Web Forms application connected to a SQL server and I am trying to pass data from one page to another. Specifically, I have a ListView ProjectList.aspx that is passing a **ProjectID** value to a FormView ProjectDetails.aspx. I am trying to setup the SQL to capture this ProjectID as the parameter of its WHERE clause.

My ProjectDetails.aspx Datasource is defined below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProjectDetailsSQL" 
                   runat="server" 
                  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 

DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblProject] WHERE [ProjectID] = @original_ProjectID" 

InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblProject] 
                          ([ProjectID], [ProjectName], [ProjectAddress], 
                           [ProjectCity], [ProjectState],[ProjectZip]) 
                    VALUES (@ProjectID, @ProjectName, @ProjectAddress, 
                            @ProjectCity, @ProjectState, @ProjectZip)" 

OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 

SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], [ProjectName], [ProjectAddress], 
                      [ProjectCity], [ProjectState], [ProjectZip]
               FROM [tblProject] WHERE ([ProjectID] = @ProjectID)" 

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblProject] 
               SET [ProjectName] = @ProjectName, 
                   [ProjectAddress] = @ProjectAddress, 
                   [ProjectCity] = @ProjectCity, 
                   [ProjectState] = @ProjectState, 
                   [ProjectZip] = @ProjectZip 
               WHERE [ProjectID] = @original_ProjectID">

<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>

<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectAddress" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectCity" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectState" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectZip" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>

<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectAddress" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectCity" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectState" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectZip" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="original_ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

I have tried passing the data as routed URL (Servername/Project/12345), explicit URL (Servername/ProjectDetails.aspx?12345) and defining the argument (Servername/ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectID=12345) and the FormView comes up blank. If I drop the `WHERE ([ProjectID] = @ProjectID)` off of the SelectCommand, the FormView shows with the first record of the table as normal.

I am guessing the problem isn't with the passing of the data and is with the WHERE clause capturing what I am trying to pass. Is there someplace else I need to define @ProjectID as the value of what I am trying to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that SqlDataSource does not have a value for the parameter, it simply has no idea where to take it from.

I am not sure SqlDataSource can work fine with url rewriting, guessing it depends on how you actually set it up. But for the latter option you have mentioned

> Servername/ProjectDetails.aspx?ProjectID=12345

There is a built-in support. Declare the parameter as query string one, and it will be taken directly from request's query string:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="ProjectID" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: That worked just fine for the fully declarative URL which will work for now. Long term I would prefer to get the URL Routing to work, but it's not a game-breaker. First step is functionality. Then once everything is fully functional will I worry about polish.

Comment: @JeffCox, if you ever get this working with url rewrite, would you mind publishing a self-answer here, or even a new one? I'd be very interested to see how you did so

Comment: if I can remember to do so, I'd be happy to. It's for a side-project at work without any hard deadlines so I have no idea if/when I'll get around to it.